# How to perform an alias configuration in an Angular + Spring Boot + Tomcat web application?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat, smtp, ip

I have a Spring Boot API that is being consumed by Angular 15 and the WEB API is running on an installed Tomcat server that is located on a local server. In this project I will be responsible for making a screen where the user can be in a “Settings” screen, and the user will be able to put the server parameters such as changing the Tomcat IP or having the option of being Default, that is, it is always localhost, and that could change the DNS. This user would have the option of making an SMTP email sending configuration where the user would inform his email so that his WEB API consumer users could contact the support area without having to enter Spring Boot to do this configuration, but through the web API itself without using a configuration file or similar

[image]

If anyone has any articles on how to do this implementation or would explain to me where to start, it would help me a lot